# iOS Localization doesn't load language

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, localization

Today I wanted to try the `localization` feature of iOS.
I added a `Localizable.strings` file to my project with the following content:

```
"TP_Start_Button" = "Workout Plan";
"TL_Start_Button" = "Training Log";
"Calc_Start_Button" = "Calculator";
```

I set the titles of three `UIButtons` like this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self.tp_start_button setTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"TP_Start_Button", nil) forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.tl_start_button setTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"TL_Start_Button", nil) forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.calc_start_button setTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Calc_Start_Button", nil) forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

After that I added another language by selecting my project and pressing the "+" button under localization. O chose German and another `Localizable.strings` was created. I replaced the content with the German translation. Then I had the following:

```
Localizable.strings
    Localizable.strings (English)
    Localizable.strings (German)
```

And in my project folder the folders `de.lproj` and `en.lproj`
were created with the `Localizable.strings` inside.

However, after starting the iPhone Simulator, English 
was loaded as the default language. After setting the language to German the language of my app didn't change. Even after deleting and reinstalling the app from my 
device it didn't work.

What do I have to do for automatically switching the language when the language in the settings is changed?

Comment: clean & re-build & deleting + reinstalling the app solved the problem. thx ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in my comment, Clean & Re-build will solve the problem.

For Localization feature, you have to `clean & rebuild` often, as this feature is cached by XCode.

Answer (score 0):

Did you add localizable.strings to target?